# Facing issue with Amplify Push (Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ")".)

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify with GraphQL to handle all my data and Lambda functions for any server side computations.

schema.graphql

```
type Media @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  userId: String! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["mediaType"])
  userName: String!
  mediaType: mediaEnum!
  integrationToken: String
  mediumUserId: String
  blogId: String
  accessToken: String
  accessTokenExpiry: AWSDateTime
  refreshToken: String
  adminApi: String
  apiUrl: String
}

type Postings @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  userMessage: String
  content: String!
  title: String!
  isMedium: Boolean!
  mediumStatus: String
  mediumUrl: String
  isBlogger: Boolean!
  bloggerStatus: String
  bloggerUrl: String
  isGhost: Boolean!
  ghostStatus: String
  ghostUrl: String
  isPinterest: Boolean!
  pinterestStatus: String
  pinterestUrl: String
  isLinkedIn: Boolean!
  linkedInStatus: String
  linkedInUrl: String
  isFacebook: Boolean!
  facebookStatus: String
  facebookUrl: String
}

type Help @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  inquiry: String!
}

type Feedback @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  emotion: userEmotion!
  negativeSelections: [String]
  positiveSelections: [String]
  featureSuggestion: String
  overallComment: String
}

type PrompterTemplate @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  templateName: String!
  ideas: String
  title: String
  audience: String
  wordCount: Int
  tone: String
  format: String
  intention: String
  keywords: [String]
  backlinkUrl: String
  backlinkDescription: String
}

type Draft @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  content: String!
  title: String
  draftName: String
}

type User @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  userId: String! @primaryKey
  userName: String!
  userEmail: String!
  phoneNumber: String!
  image: String!
  templateNo: Int!
  postingNo: Int!
  draftNo: Int!
}

type Prompt @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  userId: String!
  userName: String!
  prompt: String!
  status: String!
  result: String
  error: String
}

enum contentType {
  draft
  post
}

enum mediaEnum {
  medium
  blogger
  ghost
  pinterest
  linkedin
  facebook
}

enum userEmotion {
  annoyed
  sad
  neutral
  happy
  amazed
}

type token {
  access_token: String!
  refresh_token: String!
  scope: String!
  token_type: String!
  id_token: String!
  expires_in: Int!
}

type refreshedToken {
  access_token: String!
  scope: String!
  token_type: String!
  id_token: String!
  expires_in: Int!
}

type blogPost {
  id: String!
  status: String!
  url: String!
}

type mediumPost {
  id: String!
  url: String!
}

type Query {
  getAccessToken(authenticationCode: String!): token!
    @function(name: "getAccessToken-dev")
  postInBlogger(
    accessToken: String!
    blogId: String!
    title: String!
    content: String!
  ): blogPost! @function(name: "postToBlogger-dev")
  postInMedium(
    integrationToken: String!
    mediumUserId: String!
    title: String!
    content: String!
    backlinkUrl: String
  ): mediumPost! @function(name: "postInMedium-dev")
  refreshAccessToken(refreshToken: String!): refreshedToken!
    @function(name: "refreshAccessToken-dev")
  getMediumUserId(integrationToken: String!): String!
    @function(name: "getMediumUserId-dev")
  generateContentFromPrompter(
    ideas: String!
    title: String!
    audience: String
    wordCount: Int
    format: String
    tone: String
    intention: String
    keywords: String
    backlinkUrl: String
    backlinkDescription: String
  ): String @function(name: "generateContentFromPrompter-dev")
}
```

I am getting the following error everytime I try to amplify push or amplify update function.

Error: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found ")".

I have been stuck with this issue for quite a number of days now and I am not able to proceed any further with my development. Hope someone here can shine some light to this issue or guide me on how to resolve the above issue. Would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I went through quite a number of resources to try and fix the problematic environment but to no use. Based on professional advice, I ended up recreating the environment from scratch but now with a pinch of salt, I know to clone my env from the start and to always to make changes to staging envs first followed by prod env.